# Is there a way to gather roles from a Private Message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My bot isn't able to get roles from a Private Message!

Does anyone know how to possibly search a specific guild for the messaging member's ID and see if they have the role?

Here is an example of the code that doesn't work in a PM:

```
const Discord = require("Discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

botKey = "---";
adminRole = "---";

bot.login(botKey);
bot.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot: Ready!");
});
client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.member.roles.has(adminRole)){
    console.log(your role is Admin!);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need the guild ID. You can have the user mention the guild ID or store it somewhere. Otherwise, you can have the user mention the guild's name.

Afterwards, get the list of guilds your bot is connected to with `Client.Guilds`, it returns a `Collection<Snowflake, Guilds>`. You can either loop through it or use the `find()` method.
Note that if you are finding based on the guild's name, you have an additional step to compare against each guild's name in the collection. 
(If you are looping through it, the task will be longer if your bot is connected to a lot of guilds. Also, you can check `Client.Guilds` property [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds).)

Once you have the guild, simply fetch the GuildMember properties of the person you want. Just do `Guild.member(message.author)` and it will return a GuildMember with a similar properties of the person who just messaged you, this time with guild related properties too.

From there, you can access all the person's guild's role with `GuildMember.roles`, or if you just want to check if he have a particular permission, `GuildMember.hasPermission()` method exists.
(Docs about `GuildMember` is [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! I am still learning myself and this answer helps me understand the process. The bot only operates in 1 server, but I wouldn't know where to start and I don't find discord.js.org very useful.. or I just don't know how to read the information on it? If you are interested, could you help me understand the process of setting this up? I wish to learn how to do this

Comment: @TheBloodSeeker005 I would be glad to help (You can email me or something, just check around my profile for my email address). By the way there are examples in the discord.JS documentations, it comes with code commenting. If you do not understand those examples, I highly suggest that you should probably learn more about javascript first. (Mainly on async wise)

Comment: Okay, I'll email you. Maybe I just couldn't find the examples